# How to find the number of occurrences of a string within a huge string like a big book

Tags: c#, string, performance

I was recently asked this question during a C# interview session:

How would you efficiently find the number of occurrences of a word within a huge text like a big book (the Bible, a dictionary, etc).

I am wondering what would be the most efficient data structure to store the contents of the book in. The dirtiest soultion I could think of was to store it in a StringBuilder and find the count of the substrings, but I am sure there has to be a much better way to do this.

And for a reasonably sized string there are multiple ways of doing this using substring, regular expressions, etc but for a humongous string what is the most efficient way.

Update: What I am looking for is this:

Assuming there is a text file, lets again say the Bible, of size 20 MB, and I want to find the number of times the word "Jesus" occurs in the text, other than loading the entire 20 MB into a string or StringBuilder and using a substring or regex to find the match count, is there any other data structure that could be used to store the entire text contents. The actual search can be accomplished in multiple ways, what I am looking for is the most efficient "data structure" for the temporary storage.

Comment: The answers for "find the number of occurrences of a word within a huge text, just once" and "find the number of occurrences of a word within a huge text, more than once" are not the same. Tip for the "once" part: a book has many lines of text.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you dont care about substrings, but just full words, I would use a hashtable. Can be built in linear time and the size is proportional to the number of distinct words. `Dictionary<string,int>` specifically. On my machine, it took about 450ms  to load the entire bible into a hashtable and find all entries of the word "God".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do a full word match (can be made to work for prefix matches too).

Construct a trie from the bible with the count information.

If you need to query a word, walk the trie, get the count.

If you need to do a substring match, you can try using a suffix tree (which is basically a trie, but you also include the suffixes).

This assumes the words to query change, the bible stays fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has an interesting article on string searching:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm
and according to that article this algorithm is a sort of benchmark:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Something the size of the bible is not so huge as to prevent the entire string to be cached in memory, so with the assumption you can... I have used this method before but it obviously would not be lightning fast. Strictly speaking in terms of efficient from a computational standpoint this is not the fastest, but from a speed of coding and reasonable speed I think this works until nanoseconds count.

```
        string text = "a set of text to search in. fast to implement.";
        string key = "to";
        MessageBox.Show(text.Split(" ',.".ToCharArray()).Where(a => a == key).Count().ToString());
```

Edit: doesn't solve the final version of the question and may have misinterpretted the original question. Ignore.

Comment: This is nothing more than a simple linear search. Brute force to the extreme...at least trying to use something like a HashSet or a Dictionary would actually no slower to code, and run much, much faster.

Comment: @Timothy Baldridge Yeah, like I said in my comment. He edited his question after my response. "efficiently find the number of occurrences of a word within a huge text". Arguably doing several queries against the data this would be much slower, but a 1 time check I don't see how this is any slower than loading the hashtable up with an incrementing count and after you've iterated ALL of the values, look it up in the hashtable. Long story short, 1 lookup is probably slightly faster, but my solution doesn't work well for several lookups or memory considerations, agreed.